# importing tronweb shows import error: cannot import name 'hashable' from 'collections'

Tags: python, pip, blockchain, tron, tronweb

After installing tronweb using 'pip install tronweb', when I try to import but it shows an import error which is cannot import name 'hashable' from 'collections'

Answer (score 5):

Search by error message for the import instruction and you should **edit**:

```
from collections import Hashable
```

**to**:

```
from collections.abc import Hashable
```

It was moved from collections to collections.abc since Python 3.3. It supported the old location till Python 3.9. But in python 3.10 it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my recommendation it is better to use tronweb in a local service as an API using the latest tronweb library but in JS

Comment: Your answer isn't very clear. Please edit it to more clearly explain what you mean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).